# Get random result from table A if it exists in table B and meets the WHERE statement in the query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables; one table with users, a second table contains the categories.

On the site's frontend are a bunch of filters to filter users. One of the filters is a dropdown with checkboxes that have category values. E.g: admin, user, publisher etc can be selected.

When multiple checkboxes have been checked get a random user from users but only random user that has all selected categories.

The users have an unique id. The categories have an unique id, the category value (admin, publisher, user etc) and the user-id so it can be tied together I think.

Important note:

(`$value` = the posted value from checkbox, also keep in mind that the `categories.category = $value` part is added dynamically depending on the amount of selections, I append that using a foreach)

My current query:

```
$sql = "SELECT users.*, categories.*
       FROM users
       INNER JOIN categories
       ON users.id = categories.user_id
       WHERE categories.category = '$value' AND 
             categories.category = '$value' 
             --> continues endlessly depending on the amount of selections that have been made.
       ORDER BY RAND()
       LIMIT 0,1";
```

For some reason this only works when one checkbox is selected. When a second one, or more a selected, it breaks, no errors, it just simply doesn't find any result.

I hope my question is clear, if you need any future information, please let me know!

Comment: where is your `WHERE` in the query..?

Comment: Forgot to add it :) Added now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$values` is an array of the category IDs (I'll assume integers), you could run a query like:

```
SELECT
  users.*
FROM
  users
INNER JOIN
  categories ON users.id = categories.user_id
WHERE
  categories.category IN (" . implode(',', $values) . ")
GROUP BY
  users.id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT categories.category) >= " . count($values) . "
ORDER BY
  RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

I've made an [example fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c0eaa/2).

**Edit**

If the categories are strings then you'd need to ensure proper quotation, i.e. change the `WHERE` to:

```
categories.category IN ('" . implode("','", $values) . "')
```

Or if using prepared statements (which is ideal) you'd bind `implode(',', $values)` using:

```
FIND_IN_SET(categories.category, ?) != 0
```

Comment: I'm using varchar field for category. I get the following error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line 42. Line 42 is the start of the $sql variable. No results returned.

Comment: Dumped $sql here: string(374) "SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN categories ON users.id = categories.user_id WHERE users.prep_time+users.cook_time > '1' AND users.prep_time+users.cook_time < '541' AND categories.category IN (Appetizer) GROUP BY users.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT categories.category) >= 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"

Comment: You'll need to quote the category if it's a string, i.e. `IN ('Appetizer')`, so change the above to use `IN ('" . implode("','", $values) . "')`. Although ideally you'd you prepared statements and bind the value instead.

Comment: But it is hard to bind an `IN` list.

Comment: True. You'll use `FIND_IN_SET(category, ?) != 0` and bind `Appetizer,Main,Dessert` to the parameter in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much, I had to quote $values and then it worked fine. My question was solved!